# Increasing air intake in the attic to prevent ice buildup on the roof during winter

Tags: roof, attic, waterproofing, ventilation, ice

We bought a townhouse in 2018 in a Canadian city where we have frequent snowfall during winter. Here are pictures of the back and front of the house.
[image: Front Townhouse] [image: Back townhouse]

In the last two years, we have had [ice dams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_dam_(roof)) on both sides of the house that led to water intrusions and damage. The house was badly designed and there is insufficient ventilation of the attic during winter. The soffits air intakes are very down from the roof and it is very difficult to get the cold air up in the attic.

To prevent ice from allowing water to come in, we redid our roof with an elastomer membrane, which is what is used for flat roofs, typically:[image]

In the meantime, I still want to ventilate the roof properly so as to not have too much ice buildup. There is presently an air intake grill on top of the large window and we cut holes in the plywood during the re-roofing this year to give it access to the rest of the attic.[image]

However, we need a new way to bring cold air in from outside, especially in the back side of the roof. My plan is to cut the plywood that separates the attic from the area above the windows to increase air passage. Also, I was thinking of changing the air intakes on top of the windows that only have the small triangles in them. It doesn't seem like they allow enough air to come in.

View of the pinion from the attic:
[image: View of the pinion from the attic]

View of the air intake from the inside:
[image]

However, I am not sure which kind of air intake is installable at those areas. I was looking at installing the triangular form of [this air intake](https://ventilation-maximum.com/en/products/wall-and-soffit-air-intakes/vmax-ae-vent/), but it seems that there is a framing beam inside the pinion that would block its installation. I am not sure what are my other options to increase ventilation. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: If the inside of the attic roof is warm enough to melt the snow on the outside of the roof, in Canada, that tells me that you have a lot of heat escaping from your house into the attic.  Did you consider adding more insulation on the floor of the attic?

Comment: Yes, that is something I am planning to do as well. We were planning on doing spray foam insulation but then we chickened out at the last second when we saw that Marketplace documentary from 2013.

Comment: In that third picture, it looks like the roof slopes down towards the dormers.  Is that correct?  If so, what would help is a ridge vent or some other method of allowing air to escape at the peak of the roof.  What you're trying to achieve is some amount of air flow.

Comment: Will second the addition of ridge vents.  Want air to enter though soffets and exit from the highest points.

Comment: Yes, there is a downward slope towards the dormers. I have sloped roof ventilators installed. [link](https://ventilation-maximum.com/en/products/sloped-roof-ventilators/vmax-303/)